# Simple URL rewrite rule for IIS

Tags: iis

I need a simple URL rewrite rule for IIS. If the URL doesn't include **`"/i"`** after the domain, I would like to add it.

**For Example:**

If *www.abc.com/sample/test.aspx*

I need the rule to change it to:

*www.abc.com/i/sample/test.aspx*

Answer (score 0):

Your rule should be like that:

```
<rule name="prepend i">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/i/" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="/i/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```